# CSS makes entire HTML body disappear

Tags: html, css

My CSS page makes my entire *body* section disappear. Everything in the header appears like it should, but literally anything I put in the body will not show up.

If I take out the CSS page, it comes in just fine. But once I put the CSS page back, the body disappears. I tried just `p`, `h*`, `div`, `p` nested in `div`. Everything is closed properly; the debugger can't find anything wrong with the code.

```css
html {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Staatliches," Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* links */
    a {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:visited {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        color:#98ff98;
        font-weight: bold;
    }   
    a:active {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

/* header */
header {
    background-color: #98ff98;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #98ff98;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

#name {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Staatliches", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
}

#nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px; 
   /* removed margin: 30px auto; b/c it looked weird */
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #c8cfc8;
    border-radius: 55px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: #c8cfc8;
}

/* body? */
body {
    background-color: #c8cfc8;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Staatliches," Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
      <head>
        <title>website</title>
        <link href="resources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@400;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;700&family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <header>
          <div id="nav">
              <ul>
                  <li class="link"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="link">Contact</li>
                  <li class="link">About</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="name">
            <h1 class="name">Username</h1>
            <h4 class="minibio">tag line/one sentence bio</h4>
          </div>
        </header>
     <body>
       <p>test</p>
    
       <h1>test</h1>
    
       <div>test</div>
    
       <div>
         <p>also test</p>
      </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer here. The text is behind the header, so we just need to shift the text downwards. We can do this by adding a margin to the top of the text.

All you have to do is add the following margin-top:

```
body {
  background-color: #c8cfc8;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Staatliches," Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `postion: absolute` in your header is doing this.
It's allowing the body to go behind the header, so the body still there, but is behind the green background color.

Replacing the `position: absolute` for the desired height can do the job as I saw.

```css
html {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Staatliches," Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* links */
    a {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:visited {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        color:#98ff98;
        font-weight: bold;
    }   
    a:active {
        color:#000000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

/* header */
header {
    background-color: #98ff98;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #98ff98;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
}

body {
   display: absolute;
}

#name {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Staatliches", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
}

#nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px; 
   /* removed margin: 30px auto; b/c it looked weird */
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #c8cfc8;
    border-radius: 55px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: #c8cfc8;
}

/* body? */
body {
    background-color: #c8cfc8;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Staatliches," Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>website</title>
    <link href="resources/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@400;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@400;700&family=Staatliches&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <header>
      <div id="nav">
          <ul>
              <li class="link"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
              <li class="link">Contact</li>
              <li class="link">About</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="name">
        <h1 class="name">Username</h1>
        <h4 class="minibio">tag line/one sentence bio</h4>
      </div>
    </header>
 <body>
   <p>test</p>

   <h1>test</h1>

   <div>test</div>

   <div>
     <p>also test</p>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! simplest things sometimes

Comment: NP. If this is the solution to your problem please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As Isabelle said, your header is now sitting in front of the body.  However, another thing to note is that your header element should be *inside* the body.  The body element should contain all the other elements.  Create a div element with an id like content to use as the "body" of the page and set some padding to the top of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="link"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="link">Contact</li>
                    <li class="link">About</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="name">
                <h1 class="name">Username</h1>
                <h4 class="minibio">tag line/one sentence bio</h4>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="content">
            <p>test</p>    
            <h1>test</h1>    
            <div>test</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And add some padding

```
#content {
    padding-top: 200px;
}
```